# How to sort numpy error while importing pmdarima package in databricks

Tags: python, databricks

[Error i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIXA1.png)

I'm using arima model and I usually use jupyter notebook. I tried running the code in databricks and I'm having this issue when im trying to import pmdarima package.

for some reason i'm getting numpy has no attribute float as error when I import. I tried mutiple troubleshooting step with no success

any idea on how to solve it ?